# finding elements in an array which have greater indicies but less value in an array

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

I want to find count of elements in an array which have the following two conditions:

1. 1 <= i < j <= n
2. a[i] > a[j]

Im using the following code but i need a faster one any advice?

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    for (int j=i+1; j<n; ++j){
        if (a[j] < a[i])
            ans++;
    }
}
```

Comment: One piece of advice; regardless of what algorithm you use, test a build of your code with optimizations *enabled* (aka a Release build). Don't test a default Debug build. Compiler optimizations can make a *big* performance difference.

Comment: When you say "*faster one*" do you mean faster asymptotically for large array sizes or what array size are we talking about?

Comment: @walnut yea i mean asymptotically for large array sizes

Comment: @JesperJuhl i keep that in mind thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the number of unordered pair in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26702051/find-the-number-of-unordered-pair-in-an-array) or [Counting inversions in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337664/counting-inversions-in-an-array)

Comment: @walnut yea thats it thanks for ur help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called [inversion count](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-inversions/). Asymptotically speaking, the complexity of your current algorithm is `O(n^2)`. You can do it in `O(nlogn)` time using a merge sort based divide and conquer approach. Read more about it [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-inversions/).